# how to get particular node value fron json bing response in php

Tags: php, json, bing, bing-api

I am trying to use bing search API and i got result in JSON format, now i want get particular node value from that JSON result like(url, displayurl, snippet etc).

This is the JSON result format i got

JSON Response:

```
{
  "_type": "SearchResponse",
  "queryContext": {
    "originalQuery": "infokart India Pvt. Ltd."
  },
  "webPages": {
    "webSearchUrl": "https://www.bing.com/search?q=infokart+India+Pvt.+Ltd.",
    "totalEstimatedMatches": 12200000,
    "value": [
      {
        "id": "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v7/#WebPages.0",
        "name": "Infokart India Pvt. Ltd.",
        "url": "http://infokartindia.com/",
        "isFamilyFriendly": true,
        "displayUrl": "infokartindia.com",
        "snippet": "Journals Subscription Services,International Subscription Agency,Experiences subscription agency",
        "dateLastCrawled": "2018-07-24T11:49:00.0000000Z",
        "language": "en"
      }
    ]
  },
  "rankingResponse": {
    "mainline": {
      "items": [
        {
          "answerType": "WebPages",
          "resultIndex": 0,
          "value": {
            "id": "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v7/#WebPages.0"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Please suggest!!

Comment: Not sure that edit is better. OP format your json so that we can read it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Comment: which format you want @aandreas

Comment: Please use json_decode for converting Json to array. after that you can retrieve node value from array.

Comment: @Harinarayan Format it so that it's readable. Look at what a var_dump looks https://3v4l.org/dAbYa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 

$json = '{"_type":"SearchResponse","queryContext":{"originalQuery":"infokart India Pvt. Ltd."},"webPages":{"webSearchUrl":"https://www.bing.com/search?q=infokart+India+Pvt.+Ltd.","totalEstimatedMatches":12200000,"value":[{"id":"https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v7/#WebPages.0","name":"Infokart India Pvt. Ltd.","url":"http://infokartindia.com/","isFamilyFriendly":true,"displayUrl":"infokartindia.com","snippet":"Journals Subscription Services,International Subscription Agency,Experiences subscription agency","dateLastCrawled":"2018-07-24T11:49:00.0000000Z","language":"en"}]},"rankingResponse":{"mainline":{"items":[{"answerType":"WebPages","resultIndex":0,"value":{"id":"https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/api/v7/#WebPages.0"}}]}}}';

$json_data = json_decode($json,true);

foreach($json_data['webPages']['value'] as $each_data){
    foreach($each_data as $each_key => $each_value){
        if(in_array(strtolower($each_key),['url','displayurl','snippet'])){
            echo $each_key," => ",$each_value,"<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
url => http://infokartindia.com/
displayUrl => infokartindia.com
snippet => Journals Subscription Services,International Subscription Agency,Experiences subscription agency
```